# Process Ajax request in flask

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I've been learning flask. i've also created two projects in it. It's my third project. I'm always stuck on this point. I want to make server side code run when a event happens on page say, a button is clicked.

[In the linked image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlXEw.png) I want the entry be deleted when 'delete' button is clicked. I've holding the data on mysql server, so I want it to be deleted from there as well

Here is what I have done. I created a route `/delete_student` and it handles deleting the student.
But the problem is it's always reloading the page and also It switches to different url. I don't want any of them to happen. What should I do? Should I use Ajax, if yes, please tell me, how?

**HTML**

```
{% for i in data %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{i['roll_no']}}</td>
                <td>{{i['name']}}</td>
                <td>{{i['username']}}</td>
                <td>{{i['password']}}</td>
                <td><a href="#">Edit</a></td>
                <td><a href="{{url_for('delete_student')}}">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

**Flask**

```
@app.route('/delete_student')
@is_logged_in
def delete_student():
if session['username']=='nitti':
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    #pop the row from the table?
    #how to identify the row being deleted?
    return render_template(url_for('student_summary'))
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should access the route with javascript.

Checkout AJAX with jQuery:

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/jquery/

For example, if you have a button that says "Delete Student":

```
@app.route("/_delete_student")
def delete_student():
    student_id = request.form.get("student_id")
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cur.execute("DELETE FROM students WHERE student_id = %s", (student_id,)
    conn.commit()
    return jsonify(status="success")
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#delete_student").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: "/_delete_student",
      data: {student_id: 1},
      dataType: "text",
      success: function(data){
                 alert("Deleted Student ID "+ student_id.toString());
               }
    });
});
```

Comment: @SujeetAgrahari If you're happy with it can you accept the answer? Thanks! :)

Comment: There was an error it was returning a 'None' and the reason was that I was sending a POST request, in that case `request.args` would be a empty object.